# my editor under 'new' context menu

Tags: eclipse

I am creating plugin over Eclipse. I know how to create new project with default folders underneat. Not when a user selects this default folder and right click, the new context menu should show my_editor entry to be create under this folder.

Thanks,
Darshna

Answer (score 0):

You cannot place there your editor, what you can do is to create a "New-Wizard", for details see http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_add_my_wizard_to_the_New,_Import,_or_Export_menu_categories%3F.

how to define a new wizard and http://blog.cypal-solutions.com/2008/07/how-to-create-new-file-wizard.html how to create the wizard ui that creates a new file which can be opened with your editor.

And last but not least you need a shortcut to make it available directly under the "New" Entries, see http://blogs.itemis.de/stundzig/archives/759

Comment: Thanks Tom for your fast response.. But, I wanted the shortcut to appear under context menu. Also these shortcut showup should depends on the folder selected (eg: if main project have 2 folders fol1, fol2. Then if user selects fol1, the shourtcut under NEW should only be short1 and short2 for fol2).

Comment: First, I'm talking about the New context menu in my answer above, second, you cannot control the content of this context-menu based on a selection. Either you build your own context-menu or you check the conditions of the selections in your wizard...

Comment: Tom, it will be great help if you can share some code on shortcut showup under New context menu depending on folder selected. I googled a lot, but no materials for this. Thanks Tom.